# Issues with input and Crosswalk

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some trouble with Crosswalk with input text.

When I write something and delete it, the input doesn't clear totally. So when I write something again the old text appears in my input...

For exemple when I write "Cordova" and delete the word, and then I write "is the best", after writing "is the" it gives me "is the Cordovabest".

I didn't have this issue before installing Crosswalk. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and used this as a directive (just made it now, so not tested extensively). On the emptying of the input it creates a new input to focus on (just blur(ing) didn't do much), then re-focuses on the original input:

```js
angular.module('yourmodule')

.directive('autocomplete', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            autocomplete: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            function createInputFocus(origField) {

                origField.blur();

                var field = document.createElement('input');
                field.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                document.body.appendChild(field);

                $timeout(function() {
                    field.focus();
                    $timeout(function() {
                        field.blur();
                        document.body.removeChild(field);
                        $timeout(function() {
                             origField.focus();
                         }, 100);
                    }, 100);
                });
            }

            if (attrs.autocomplete === 'off') {

                element[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                    if (element[0].value !== undefined && !element[0].value.length) {
                        createInputFocus(element[0]);
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off">
```

Seems to do the trick for me!